# How does this simplify to 1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I am working on this differetiation problem:

$ \frac{d}{dx}x(1-\frac{2}{x})$

and I am currently stuck at this point:

$1\cdot \left(1-\frac{2}{x}\right)+\frac{2}{x^2}x$

Symbolab tells me this simplifies to $1$ but I do not understand how. I am under the impression that;

$1\cdot \left(1-\frac{2}{x}\right)+\frac{2}{x^2}x \equiv 1- 2x^{-x^2}-2^{-x}$

Comment: what kind of reasoning did you use for your last line? that's a good one...^^

Comment: i see: $n/x=(-)^n nx^{-x^n}$...you made my day (+1)

Comment: $2x \div (x \dot x) = 2x^{-x^2}$

Comment: You are confusing $a/x=ax^{-1}$ and $a^{-x}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Do not get confused by fractions and exponents.**
You should remember that $\frac {k}{n} = kn^{-1}$ and not $k^{-n} $ and that $\frac {k}{n} l = kln^{-1}$ and not $kl^{-n} $.

We have $$1\times (1-\frac {2}{x}) = 1-\frac {2}{x} \tag {1}$$ and then $$\frac {2}{x^2}x = \frac {2}{x^2} \times x = \frac {2}{x} \tag {2} $$

What do we get by adding $(1)$ and $(2)$? The result is $1-\frac {2}{x} + \frac {2}{x} = 1$. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

$1\cdot \left(1-\frac{2}{x}\right)+\frac{2}{x^2}x $

= $1\cdot 1- 1 \cdot \frac{2}{x} + \frac{2}{x}$

= $1- \frac{2}{x} + \frac{2}{x}$

=$1$

Answer (score 1):

$$1\cdot (1-\frac2x) + \frac{2}{x^2}x = 1-\frac2x + \frac2x = 1$$ for all $x\neq 0$.

I have no idea where you got $x^{-x^2}$ from...

Comment: The $x^2$ was obviously taken from the denominator and scrambled with a $-1$ exponent.